# Dynamic width with multiple elements

Tags: css, width, element

I'm trying to find a pure CSS way to have 1 or more elements inline and have them adjust their width to fill the container e.g.

1 element

[------]

2 elements

[---***]

3 elements

[--**..]

Is this achievable through pure CSS?

Comment: can you share what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use display: table on parent, and display: table-cell on children.
then you can add as many inner div's as you wish.
Like this:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner">1</div>
    <div class="inner">2</div>
    <div class="inner">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
 display: table;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    outline: 1px solid blue;
}
```

here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w8p2nj9z/